# Activate alarm from button click on android

Tags: android

How do I activate an alarm in android for a set amount of time when for example, a button is clicked? Do I have to add my own alarm audio to the project?

EDIT: Here is some code that works but I want it to play for a minute not just a second, is there any way of doing this?

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
if(alert == null){
alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
}
if(alert == null) {
alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);  
}
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), alert);
mp.start();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Vibration:
set the perrmission in manifest
create a Vibrator object in Code
check if the phone provides vibration at all
then use the methods of the Vibrator class to let the phone vibrate

Alarm: Yes your own is the fastest solution

else create an alarm with the alrmmanager and let a broadcastreceiver do sth....by sth i mean play an audio file or display a notification or a toast or sth like that...